# Why was this edit rejected?

Tags: discussion

I was replacing 'bare' with 'bear' (which is the word that fits properly in the sentence). I certainly wasn't mentioning about any bears in the show.

FYI - [Bare vs Bear](http://grammarist.com/spelling/bare-bear/)

[image]

Comment: Half of the edits you suggested were non-necessary.

Comment: @Catija Yet the other half fixed actual errors.

Comment: Mmm - is it possible the meaning of 'dead like the others' was interpreted as being different than 'destroyed the same way'.  The original carries more intent that its Dexter's actions that are destroying people's lives.  Tenuous I guess.

Comment: @Catija you guys are right. I might have gone overboard with the corrections and the reviewer probably wanted to keep his original answer untouched. I understand that. But I was perplexed by the reason given for the rejection though. "there are no bears in the tv series" :|

Comment: tagging @iandotkelly

Comment: @bizentass yeah, that was my fault for sure for the bear part. But the rest of edits was also not what i want. It should have better be improved rather then complete reject. I will invite you to submit the edit again without the unnecessary changes.

Comment: @AnkitSharma okay i'll do that. Thank you.

Comment: I believe edits like his improve the grammar of the answer, which in turn improves the answer. I've noticed, especially on SO, that a significant number of posts have grammar mistakes ranging from the minute to the outrageous. Sometimes, these mistakes can make the answer convoluted. I also believe that for new users, letting them go through many answers and edit them to gain rep is a fair way of doing so; it shows they are willing to take the time to create a better answer.

Comment: @AnkitSharma there have been many posts (comments/answers) of yours that need some editing; I don't blame you for it. I presume you are not a native English speaker, so there will be times when you make mistakes (forgetting a conjugation, using a gerund incorrectly - I see it all the time with non-English speakers). These grammar fixes will help improve the quality of your answers, and will in turn help you learn better grammar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in comment, It was my fault for the bear part.

But the rest of edits was also not what i wanted. It should have better be an improvement over your edit rather then complete reject. I will invite you to submit the edit again without the unnecessary changes.